# How to wrap an activity inside fragment container

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using a bottom navigation bar within my app, i have one main activity that uses a container to access different fragments, however one of my tabs requires an activity that uses fragments inside it and im unsure how i should go about transferring this to keep my navigation bar as i lose it? Should i have to code in my navigation bar within the activity or transfer the activity to fragment? I did originally try this but because i use a searchbar that covers the separate fragments within the other activity, its hard to transfer over.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener bottomNav = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {


        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(menuItem.getItemId()).setChecked(true);
        switch(menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.map:
                selectedFragment = new Map();
                newSighting.show();

                break;

            case R.id.prof:
                selectedFragment = new Prof();

                break;

            case R.id.dek:
                selectedFragment = new Delete();
                break;


            case R.id.tab:

               Intent k = new Intent(Home.this, Tab.class);
                startActivity(k);
                return true;
        }


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,
                selectedFragment).commit();
        return false;

    }
};
```

I have attached my code for my bottom navigation with the main activity.

Comment: why do you need the activity? you can put fragments inside of a fragment with something like a view pager

Comment: @JRowan I would like the toolbar to be used across the fragments within the container, using a fragment im unsure how to